# cannot launch Microsoft android emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio, emulation

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 professional.

I know the emulator is  But, I cannot launch the emulator though I had reinstalled it.
Can you help me fix it? Thank you!

[image]

```
 its the log15.11.7 10:38:03: [Informational] ===== Session Started =====
15.11.7 10:38:03: [Informational] Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.10240.0 Windows 10 Pro
15.11.7 10:38:03: [Informational] Virtualization type: UnknownOrNotVirtual
15.11.7 10:38:03: [Informational] Virtualization Version: bios date: 11/14/11 10:19:57 ver: 04.06.04
15.11.7 10:38:03: [Informational] Virtualization Serial Number: 5k5mjr1
15.11.7 10:38:03: [Informational] Virtualization Product: 0ggrv5
15.11.7 10:38:03: [Informational] Display Adapter 0: Name: AMD Radeon HD 7400M Series, Version: 15.200.1023.7
15.11.7 10:38:03: [Informational] Display Adapter 1: Name: Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000, Version: 9.17.10.4229
15.11.7 10:38:04: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
15.11.7 10:38:04: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 0 Platforms: 2
15.11.7 10:38:04: [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Warning] The platform profile specified by the device profile with ID '207505CA-D7AE-405D-9D8E-43A7B0E8971E' and version '1.0.50925.1' could not be found. The device profile will not be loaded. Please correct the platform specification and reload the manager.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Warning] The platform profile specified by the device profile with ID '15BBA308-E791-46B1-8475-415BA579CBB9' and version '1.0.50925.1' could not be found. The device profile will not be loaded. Please correct the platform specification and reload the manager.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Warning] The platform profile specified by the device profile with ID 'D76C4650-7EFD-4D9F-8AA6-126F42C71E2C' and version '1.0.50925.1' could not be found. The device profile will not be loaded. Please correct the platform specification and reload the manager.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Warning] The platform profile specified by the device profile with ID '16BAD6E1-57FC-4586-A0B5-D5D8834AB623' and version '1.0.50925.1' could not be found. The device profile will not be loaded. Please correct the platform specification and reload the manager.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Warning] The platform profile specified by the device profile with ID '750E474F-A8AE-4757-BB0F-FE32118D868A' and version '1.0.50925.1' could not be found. The device profile will not be loaded. Please correct the platform specification and reload the manager.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Warning] The platform profile specified by the device profile with ID 'A27369D5-0BF4-46C6-8013-AC2C15321BB8' and version '1.0.50925.1' could not be found. The device profile will not be loaded. Please correct the platform specification and reload the manager.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Warning] The platform profile specified by the device profile with ID '2157ED0C-C71B-40FF-A26B-FC3CE6FF01FA' and version '1.0.50925.1' could not be found. The device profile will not be loaded. Please correct the platform specification and reload the manager.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Warning] The platform profile specified by the device profile with ID 'C7675B16-D0CA-451A-815B-52C48A29D78C' and version '1.0.50925.1' could not be found. The device profile will not be loaded. Please correct the platform specification and reload the manager.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Warning] The platform profile specified by the device profile with ID '61B433CF-8C92-4CEA-9CA1-009DC946ED7E' and version '1.0.50925.1' could not be found. The device profile will not be loaded. Please correct the platform specification and reload the manager.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Warning] The platform profile specified by the device profile with ID 'B2BAA1A0-2240-4A41-8A4C-7EC1AC991DD6' and version '1.0.50925.1' could not be found. The device profile will not be loaded. Please correct the platform specification and reload the manager.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Warning] The platform profile specified by the device profile with ID '0076019F-F03D-41CC-984F-D92FCBD52648' and version '1.0.50925.1' could not be found. The device profile will not be loaded. Please correct the platform specification and reload the manager.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Warning] The platform profile specified by the device profile with ID '32C559A4-8723-40BD-B4ED-4DB4EBB45C75' and version '1.0.50925.1' could not be found. The device profile will not be loaded. Please correct the platform specification and reload the manager.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Warning] The platform profile specified by the device profile with ID 'B7694724-5A2A-4CCA-914F-55F72B72A919' and version '1.0.50925.1' could not be found. The device profile will not be loaded. Please correct the platform specification and reload the manager.
15.11.7 10:38:14: [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 17 Platforms: 2
15.11.7 10:38:24: [Informational] Waiting to install device...
15.11.7 10:38:24: [Informational] Installing Device: 4.5" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Phone , Version: 1.0.50925.1
15.11.7 10:38:24: [Informational] Creating device configuration
15.11.7 10:38:24: [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
15.11.7 10:38:24: [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 1 Platforms: 2
15.11.7 10:38:25: [Informational] Copying .vhd files and creating virtual machine
15.11.7 10:39:26: [Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 4.5" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Phone' device.
15.11.7 10:39:26: [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\xde.exe
15.11.7 10:39:26: [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 4.5\" Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Phone" /memSize 1024 /diagonalSize 4.5 /video "720x1280" /vhd "C:\Users\LSQ\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\4.5_Lollipop_(5.1.1)_XHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 4.5-inch Lollipop (5.1.1) XHDPI Phone.lsq" /noStart /silent
15.11.7 10:39:26: [Critical] XDE Exit Code: Unknown (-532462766)
```

Comment: it returns that "we encountered a problem while installing this profile.please try again or see log file for details"

Comment: you should write for the microsoft visual studio team or to the msdn forum

Comment: try to use Genymotion.(https://www.genymotion.com).Iam using it with Android Studio.